# I want to look if the cell value begins with the letters "PP*"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

In excel I used this code in columnR:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(RC[-14],"*PP*")>0,"N",VLOOKUP(RC[-7],Mapping!R2C1:R22C19,2,FALSE)"
```

Now I wanted to turn it into VBA code.

In column D(RC-14) it looks if the word contains PP if so gives a N. When the word doesn't contain the letter PP then the Vlookup is used.

This is the code below: it does not spot when the value in D starts with PP* and always go to the else loop. Can somebody help me please :)

```
Dim RowCounter As Integer
RowCounter = 1

While wsBPT.Range("A1").Offset(RowCounter, 0).Value <> ""   'only fill in when there is data
If wsBPT.Range("D1").Offset(RowCounter, 0).Value = "*PP*" Then   'when isin starts with PP
        wsBPT.Range("A1").Offset(RowCounter, 17).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP("PP",'Mapping'!R2C1:R10C2,2,FALSE)"
        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
    Else: wsBPT.Range("A1").Offset(RowCounter, 17).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'Mapping'!R2C1:R10C2,2,FALSE)" 'isin doesnot contain PP
        RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
End If
        Wend
```

Comment: `.Value Like "PP*"`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Yew it workeddd!!!

Comment: `If Left(wsBPT.Range("D1").Offset(RowCounter, 0).Value, 3) = "PP*" Then`

Comment: it worked thank you!

Comment: Are you doing a A LOT of rows? Your code will be very slow. There are much quicker ways to go about this.

Comment: @scottCraner, I have another question; I have this code to clean up my worksheet but sometimes it doesnt work properly. Why?

Call public_constants
wsBPT.Cells.ClearContents
wsDashboard.Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Shape02").Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = 11

Comment: New Questions get new posts

Comment: @ExcelHero, wat is the quicker way? I have 300 rows

Comment: How long does it take to run on the 300 rows?

Comment: I just ran the macro, about 5sec